# Google not indexing a recent WordPress post

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

Recently I've published my recent WordPress post on my blog. Normally whenever I post something on my blog It gets indexed almost instantly. But that didn't happen with my recent post.

I've asked from some of my colleagues about this incident and they told google can take up to 4 to 5 days to index new content. So I checked after 3 days by searching site:mydomain.com and I got my new post in results.
In fact, it was ranking on the first page with targeted keywords.

But now after a week, It is again removed from the Google index. even its not coming by typing site:example.com.

I think this post appears to be suspicious to google bot because of this paragraph:

> After implementing this technique I had reduced the response time from
>   1.5  seconds to under 170 milliseconds. So you can expect a 94% reduction in server response time if you also have a response time of
>   1.5 seconds or above.

Also, I've tried requesting google to index the new post from google webmaster.

**Not** this question is not only about Google not indexing a page. Google did index this page but now it has been removed from the index.

**Update**
The content in the post is 100 % unique.

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked many times in various forms.